# Linq 2 SQL - Inheritance Multiple SQL Statements

Tags: sql, linq, inheritance, linq-to-sql

Whilst implementing the AdventureWorks db in a sample application using Linq 2 SQL i've ran into a problem with the way in which Linq 2 SQL generates SQL statements for derived types in the inheritance mapping defined in my DBML.

I have two entities in my DBML, Person and PersonPhone (one Person to many PersonPhones) WITHOUT any inheritance mapping defined (Person will be a inheritance base class in a later example).  If I then run the following Linq statement I notice that whilst doing a trace the following SQL is generated as expected:

```
void Main()
{
this.DeferredLoadingEnabled = false;

DataLoadOptions dlo = new DataLoadOptions();
dlo.LoadWith<Person>(n => n.PersonPhones);
this.LoadOptions = dlo;

Person person = this.Persons.SingleOrDefault(n => n.BusinessEntityID == 291);
person.PersonPhones.Dump(); 
}

DECLARE @p0 Int = 291
SELECT [t0].[BusinessEntityID], [t0].[PersonType], [t0].[NameStyle], [t0].[Title], [t0].[FirstName], [t0].[MiddleName], [t0].[LastName], [t0].[Suffix], [t0].[EmailPromotion], [t0].[AdditionalContactInfo], [t0].[Demographics], [t0].[rowguid], [t0].[ModifiedDate], [t1].[BusinessEntityID] AS [BusinessEntityID2], [t1].[PhoneNumber], [t1].[PhoneNumberTypeID], [t1].[ModifiedDate] AS [ModifiedDate2], (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [Person].[PersonPhone] AS [t2]
    WHERE [t2].[BusinessEntityID] = [t0].[BusinessEntityID]
    ) AS [value]
FROM [Person].[Person] AS [t0]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Person].[PersonPhone] AS [t1] ON [t1].[BusinessEntityID] = [t0].[BusinessEntityID]
WHERE [t0].[BusinessEntityID] = @p0
ORDER BY [t0].[BusinessEntityID], [t1].[PhoneNumber], [t1].[PhoneNumberTypeID]
```

The result is that the SQL is generated in a single statement.  Please ignore the fact that this might be inefficient SQL, the point i'm making is that its ran in a single statement.

But if I include inheritance mapping information in my DBML and define a new entity type called StoreContact (derives from Person) and run the exact same query I actually get different results as shown below.  In that TWO SQL statements are actually run.

```
DECLARE @p0 Int = 291
SELECT [t0].[PersonType], [t0].[BusinessEntityID], [t0].[NameStyle], [t0].[Title], [t0].[FirstName], [t0].[MiddleName], [t0].[LastName], [t0].[Suffix], [t0].[EmailPromotion], [t0].[AdditionalContactInfo], [t0].[Demographics], [t0].[rowguid], [t0].[ModifiedDate]
FROM [Person].[Person] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[BusinessEntityID] = @p0
GO

DECLARE @x1 Int = 291
SELECT [t0].[BusinessEntityID], [t0].[PhoneNumber], [t0].[PhoneNumberTypeID], [t0].[ModifiedDate]
FROM [Person].[PersonPhone] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[BusinessEntityID] = @x1
```

This is somewhat problematic in that this will reduce the speed of our applications rather substantially in that Linq 2 SQL is required to make duplicate calls to the DB in the case of implementing the inheritance feature.  Looks like having an OOP model does come at a cost.

Is there a workaround for this problem to make the SQL run in a single statement?

Comment: A point I should express is that in this example I'm using the SAME linq statement both before and after the inheritance mapping change.

Comment: Why does the first SQL do counting? Does L2S insert this horrible aggregate or is that from your code?

Comment: Because 'query' isn't ran against the db until the following line is executed: ac.PersonPhones.Count.Dump(), therefore it translates it into the most appropriate SQL statement based upon the linq statement.   This is just an example of when it has performed the linq query in a single SQL statement in which I'm trying to achieve with inheritance, the fact that it might have generated inefficient SQL doesn't really matter because I can rewrite my Linq query to be more efficient for the purpose of doing a count.

Comment: `ac.PersonPhones` is *not* `Iqueryable`. LINQ does not optimize this in any way. This statement cannot possibly influence the execution of `query`. Right now I have doubts that the code shown corresponds to the SQL shown. Can you review this? Maybe single-step through and observe which lines generate which SQL.

Comment: I've double-checked and confirm that the Linq code provided in the example generates the stated SQL statement.  I have checked this through using LinqPad which details the SQL queries executed and against SQL Server Profiler.  The SQL which has been generated in the example makes sense, I wouldn't expect anything different based upon the linq query i have written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately not the answer I'm looking for but an upgrade to the Entity Framework would resolve the problem whilst maintaining the inheritance.

If I run the following EF equivalent query:

```
void Main()
{
    StoreContact person  =(StoreContact)this.People.Include("PersonPhones").SingleOrDefault(n => n.BusinessEntityID == 291);
    person.PersonPhones.Dump(); 
}
```

I get the following SQL result:

```
SELECT 
[Project2].[BusinessEntityID] AS [BusinessEntityID], 
[Project2].[C1] AS [C1], 
[Project2].[NameStyle] AS [NameStyle], 
[Project2].[Title] AS [Title], 
[Project2].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
[Project2].[MiddleName] AS [MiddleName], 
[Project2].[LastName] AS [LastName], 
[Project2].[Suffix] AS [Suffix], 
[Project2].[EmailPromotion] AS [EmailPromotion], 
[Project2].[AdditionalContactInfo] AS [AdditionalContactInfo], 
[Project2].[Demographics] AS [Demographics], 
[Project2].[rowguid] AS [rowguid], 
[Project2].[ModifiedDate] AS [ModifiedDate], 
[Project2].[C2] AS [C2], 
[Project2].[BusinessEntityID1] AS [BusinessEntityID1], 
[Project2].[PhoneNumber] AS [PhoneNumber], 
[Project2].[PhoneNumberTypeID] AS [PhoneNumberTypeID], 
[Project2].[ModifiedDate1] AS [ModifiedDate1]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Limit1].[BusinessEntityID] AS [BusinessEntityID], 
    [Limit1].[NameStyle] AS [NameStyle], 
    [Limit1].[Title] AS [Title], 
    [Limit1].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
    [Limit1].[MiddleName] AS [MiddleName], 
    [Limit1].[LastName] AS [LastName], 
    [Limit1].[Suffix] AS [Suffix], 
    [Limit1].[EmailPromotion] AS [EmailPromotion], 
    [Limit1].[AdditionalContactInfo] AS [AdditionalContactInfo], 
    [Limit1].[Demographics] AS [Demographics], 
    [Limit1].[rowguid] AS [rowguid], 
    [Limit1].[ModifiedDate] AS [ModifiedDate], 
    [Limit1].[C1] AS [C1], 
    [Extent2].[BusinessEntityID] AS [BusinessEntityID1], 
    [Extent2].[PhoneNumber] AS [PhoneNumber], 
    [Extent2].[PhoneNumberTypeID] AS [PhoneNumberTypeID], 
    [Extent2].[ModifiedDate] AS [ModifiedDate1], 
    CASE WHEN ([Extent2].[BusinessEntityID] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C2]
    FROM   (SELECT TOP (2) 
        [Extent1].[BusinessEntityID] AS [BusinessEntityID], 
        [Extent1].[NameStyle] AS [NameStyle], 
        [Extent1].[Title] AS [Title], 
        [Extent1].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
        [Extent1].[MiddleName] AS [MiddleName], 
        [Extent1].[LastName] AS [LastName], 
        [Extent1].[Suffix] AS [Suffix], 
        [Extent1].[EmailPromotion] AS [EmailPromotion], 
        [Extent1].[AdditionalContactInfo] AS [AdditionalContactInfo], 
        [Extent1].[Demographics] AS [Demographics], 
        [Extent1].[rowguid] AS [rowguid], 
        [Extent1].[ModifiedDate] AS [ModifiedDate], 
        '0X0X' AS [C1]
        FROM [Person].[Person] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE 291 = [Extent1].[BusinessEntityID] ) AS [Limit1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [Person].[PersonPhone] AS [Extent2] ON [Limit1].[BusinessEntityID] = [Extent2].[BusinessEntityID]
)  AS [Project2]
ORDER BY [Project2].[BusinessEntityID] ASC, [Project2].[C2] ASC
```

The SQL statement returns the results within a single query.

The reason this isn't the answer i'm looking for is that for a transition from Linq to SQL to Entity Framework for an existing application is a rather big step.